# Define: maximal nonvanishing determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Part of a question given to me stated:

> Determine the order of the maximal nonvanishing determinant in the matrix of coefficients.

The matrix in question is $\left(\begin{matrix}2&1&2&1&3\\5&3&-4&3&-6\\1&1&-8&1&-12\\\end{matrix}\right)$.

What is the maximal nonvanishing determinant? I know what a determinant is, but what is a maximal determinant?

Comment: I think they want the maximum non-zero determinant.

Comment: Out of all square submatrices, what is the largest submatrix with nonzero determinant?

Comment: @Joppy So I would find the determinants of any square matrices that make up this matrix?

Comment: Yes: you're just looking for the maximum size such that a submatrix has nonzero determinant. I can already see that there is 1x1 submatrix with nonzero determinant, so you need to see if there are any 2x2. If you find one, then look at 3x3 submatrices. (Or perhaps there is a better way...)